# Resize Elements on Container without changing Layout

Tags: java, resize, jframe

we are using the absolute Layout and we are looking for a quick way to resize all components inclusive Fontsizes when resizing the frame. Is there some method that can do this?

We could program it ourselves, but it would take too much efford i think, so we thought maybe there already exists a way of doing this.

Sincerely

Kev

Comment: Yeah, using appropriate layout managers (it's why they are there) or make your own layout management API, those are your two choices

Comment: that's not true, i could easily program a resize function that runs through all components in a frame, the layout manager is irrelevant in that case, the only question i had was if there is a method already implemented in java that can do this, would save a lot of time

Comment: So, you mean, make you're own layout management API and reinvent the wheel?  *"the only question i had was if there is a method already implemented in java that can do this, would save a lot of time"* - Yes, the layout management API

Comment: that's not what we are looking for, but still thanks for the comments.  In Visual Foxpro for example there exists a class which automatically resizes all components on a form when the resize function is activated, that was what i was looking for... the layout in that case, like i said, is irrelevant